# Why Fernet.encode() giving me this error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, replit

So I'm trying to code a Caesar Cipher for my python course. Here is my code so far:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

direction = input("Type 'encode' to encrypt, type 'decode' to decrypt:\n")
text = input("Type your message:\n").lower()
shift = int(input("Type the shift number:\n"))

encrypt = Fernet.encrypt(text.encode(text))
```

But it keeps on giving me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
    encrypt = Fernet.encrypt(text.encode(text))
LookupError: unknown encoding: hi
```

Note:
i inputted hi for text. Maybe is that giving the error?

Comment: `text.encode(text)` tries to encode (read: change into bytes) the variable `text` with the encoding-type of the variable-value of `text`. If `text = "hi"`, then you would get that error. The error doesn't have anything to do with the `Fernet.encrypt()` method.

Comment: Try: `text.encode("ascii")` or `str.encode(text, "ascii")`

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

Your code is causing a `LookupError` because the `encode()` method is being called with an invalid argument; it happens due to `encode()` should be the name of the encoding to use, such as `'utf-8'`, not the input message itself. Additionally, `Fernet.encrypt()` should be called on an instance of the `Fernet` class, not the class itself.

### Fixed Script:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

direction = input("Type 'encode' to encrypt, type 'decode' to decrypt:\n")
text = input("Type your message:\n").lower()
shift = int(input("Type the shift number:\n"))

cipher_key = Fernet.generate_key()
cipher_suite = Fernet(cipher_key)
encrypted_text = cipher_suite.encrypt(text.encode())

print(f"Encrypted message: {encrypted_text}")
```

### Execution

```
$ python fernet.py
Type 'encode' to encrypt, type 'decode' to decrypt:
encode
Type your message:
hi
Type the shift number:
5
Encrypted message: b'gAAAAABj_RPpE-tfRe8azmIBrYr5rPi3hQaspJO2geEZL92jvC0HQZnrswAC1ihdbD5ItrtRNix8qNmiunkdaygCwGe-KmK5sg=='
```

---

## In more detail

It is causing a `LookupError` because the `encode()` method converts a Unicode string to a bytes object. It can take an optional argument that specifies the name of the encoding to use. For example, you are using `encode()` to call `text` as an argument, which is a string containing the input message, causing the error because it isn't the name of an encoding.

Another issue is that `Fernet.encrypt()` is being called on the `Fernet` class itself, not an instance of the class. To fix this, an instance of the `Fernet` class should be created first, and then the `encrypt()` method should be called on that instance.